# DNS issue with Azure - gives error when using DNS

Tags: url, azure

I am facing a strange issue with azure -

After uploading a new version of my app about an hour back, the public facing url is throwing a runtime error. However the app works fine when I access it through the azure internal domain -- *app*.cloudapp.net.

Before upgrading it was working fine.

I have rechecked the cname records with my hosting provider (bluehost) but I cannot find any problem. Even otherwise, the problem seems like an ASP.net issue (due to the typical error page rendered) but something that just does not make sense.

Anyone has any ideas as to what I can do?

EDIT: This started working just as mysteriously as it had stopped - I have no clue whether it is due to DNS propagation delay (although in that case it should not have thrown an error page like described above). However if someone knows why this might happen, I will still appreciate it.

Comment: Hum, is your app even aware of the host headers being passed through HTTP requests? In a classical ASP.NET design, the DNS setup is not supposed to have any impact.

Comment: No, thats what is strange - it is supposed to work fine without any knowledge of the actual dns setup. That's why I think this is an azure specific issue. However, this also started working as mysteriously as it had stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a DNS service available for Windows Azure called "DNS Azure" that changes your cloudapp's IP address automatically. See dnsazure.com
This solutions helps to avoid the CNAME record because the A record is kept up-to-date.